# display facebook wall in android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I've been working with the facebook-android-sdk and integrated posting a message to the user's wall. I've got the posting working, however I want to display the user's wall with the new post so they can view it.

Does the sdk implement this functionality through Dialogs somewhow or do I need to load the Graph API URL through a webview in Android? (going off the info here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: What API do you use to post to the user's wall?

Comment: I'm using the facebook-android-sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying the stream (aka wall/feed/posts)

overall information:
see: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/stream

Java code here for how to render: 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/stream/src/com/facebook/stream/StreamRenderer.java

Comment: Hey, after monkeying around using the WebView route below I realized it's not such a robust solution. Links in the WebView open the browser which creates confusion. Going to reimplement with your suggestion. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Links aren't working any more. Couldn't  find new links.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging around, I just went ahead and used a Webview.

...

```
public void onComplete (Bundle values)
            {
                      Log.d (TAG, "onComplete()");
              Toast.makeText (getBaseContext (), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                  editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                  editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                  editor.commit();

                      // post the message 
                  postMessageOnWall ("");

                      // we're already authenticated so just go to the user's wall in a webview
                  WebView mWebView;
                  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_fb);
                  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                  mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?&sk=wall");
            }
```

...

Comment: try this after the user posts:
Bundle params = new Bundle();
Utility.mFacebook.dialog(this, "../home.php", params, new ActionListener());
doesn't always load the first time though but it seems to work.